# Trivial assertion violation in Dafny

Tags: dafny

Why does Dafny claim this simple assertion is possibly violated?

```
var b := new int[2];
b[0],b[1] := 1, -2;
assert exists k | 0 <= k < b.Length :: (b[k] == 1 || b[k] == -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way Dafny handles existential quantifiers. It will (almost) never "guess" a value for you. Instead, Dafny uses syntactic heuristics (called "triggers") to try certain values from the context.

In your assertion, the trigger is `b[k]`, which means that Dafny will only try values of `k` such that the expression `b[k]` is mentioned explicitly.

Thus, one way to fix the assertion is to explicitly mention the correct value for `k`, by adding the assertion

```
assert b[0] == 1;
```

or even

```
assert b[0] == 1 || b[0] == -1
```

---

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723710/dafny-array-elements-contained-in-other-array-assertion).

For more on triggers see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399562/438267).